# Access POST vars - Java EE Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How can i access my POST vars in my servlet ?

I tried

```
String login = (String) request.getAttribute("login");
String password = (String) request.getAttribute("password");
```

My HTML form

```html
<form action="login" class="form-group" method="POST" style="width: 300px;">
    Nom d'utilisateur <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" />
    Mot de passe <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are parameters, not attributes, use [`ServletRequest#getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getParameter` method [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```